# При определенном разрешении экрана выполнить скрипт единожды

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `html` который формируется единожды при загрузке страницы, потом вносятся изменения тем же `js`, и при определенном разрешении необходимо сбросить весь сформированный `html`, событие `resize`.

Суть вопроса, как выполнить скрипт единожды?

```js
function obnovitStranicu() {
  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
    location.reload();
  }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  obnovitStranicu();
});
```

Comment: Чё-то странное решение... Задумайтесь, правильно ли оно всё получается-то. А чтобы выполнить единожды, нужно не записывать его в обработчик событий `resize`, а записать как функцию отдельно и, когда нужно, вызвать её просто.

Comment: Выполнить его можно если он не относится к перезагрузке страницы, иначе у вас весь код будет перевыполнен заново. Если вам все же нужно после перезагрузки выполнить скрипт, придется писать в `localStorage`

Comment: Вам надо сделать не просто reload, а передать на сервер параметр (можно через куку или в качестве параметров запроса) что сейчас вы выполняете контролируемый reload, и серверная часть в этом случае должна отдать страницу без этого куска кода. Ну и заодно решить что такое "единожды" и сохранить у себя в данных сессии например, что такая перезагрузка выполнялась и еще возможно запомнить разрешение на котором она выполнялась, что бы включить опять этот код если разрешение изменится

Comment: @Mike оба варианта я сделал чисто на клиентской стороне, не нагружая сервером, но вы правильно подметили для создателя вопроса, что непонятно что такое "единожды"

Comment: Сразу извиняюсь, бывает трудно донести суть. Аналогичный задуманному пример http://www.north2.net/projects/?browser=full В моем примере код вызывается пока значение меньше, можно сделать знак равенства! но он бывает проскакивает.... И срабатывает не всегда.

Comment: Допустим когда значение меньше 320px обновить страницу , кода больше 320px обновить еще раз, выходит необходимо под различные разрешения обновлять страницу. На первый взгляд все элементарно, но как-бы не так.\

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно проверять в масштабах одной страницы/каждой отдельной

```js
(function() {
  var onResizeHandler = function(event) {
    if (this.innerWidth < 470) {
      console.log('Делаем что-то 1 раз');
      // Действия
      $(window).unbind('resize', onResizeHandler);
    }
  };

  $(window).bind('resize', onResizeHandler);
})();
```

Если нужно проверять 1 раз, при использовании когда либо, и больше никогда

```js
(function() {
  // localStorage.clear()
  // Проверяем была ли инициирована переменная выполнения нашего условия
  var isExecuted = localStorage.getItem('isExecuted') === 'true';

  // И если нет, создаем обработчик и подписываемся на событие
  if (!isExecuted) {
    var onResizeHandler = function(event) {
      console.log(this.innerWidth)
      if (this.innerWidth < 470) {
        console.log('Делаем что-то 1 раз');

        // Условие совершилось, значит запишем значение в память страницы
        localStorage.setItem('isExecuted', true);
        // И удалим обработчик на текущий момент, чтобы не грузить страницу
        $(window).unbind('resize', onResizeHandler);
      }
    };

    $(window).bind('resize', onResizeHandler);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!, на свежую голову подумал, выходит если событие приводит к перезагрузки страницы, весь результат пропадает, может что-то на этой основе придумаю :)

Answer (score -1):

Если правильно понял:

```
function obnovitStranicu() 
{ 
  location.reload();
};

if (  $(window).width() < 470  )
  obnovitStranicu();
```

Comment: Ваш метод вызовется единожды? Нет. У вас вообще странный пример. При изменении размеров экрана, у вас ничего не произойдет. Ваш пример не выполняет условий, которые требуются

Comment: @Василий, метод вызывается единожды. Когда я писал ответ, вопрос был плохо сформирован, и получилось, что я не так ответил)